# I can't set repeating of AlarmManager using setExact()

Tags: android

I tried to set repeating AlarmManager using setExact. In activity:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.setAction(ACTION_ALARM_RETRY);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); 
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 7000, sender);`
```

And in receiver after my operations I have:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
  //Here are my operations...
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
  intent.setAction(ACTION_ALARM_RETRY);
  PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intet, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); 
  alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 7000, sender);
}
```

But it repeats all time without foggiest pause...
Help please!

Comment: I'm not sure how that's working at all, but the first argument in the `setExact()` method needs to be the alarm type - e.g., `AlarmManager.RTC` - and the second is the time in milliseconds, the value of which depends on the type.

Comment: Thanks! I've already edited question.

Comment: Since your alarm is based on the real-time clock, `7000` is always going to be in the past, so the alarms are firing immediately. If you want a 7 second interval, it would be `System.currentTimeMillis() + 7000`. However, with an interval that short, you probably don't want to use `AlarmManager`.